# Compensating for differing xdpi and ydpi with OpenGL10 ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have got as far as using OpenGL 10 ES to render my product boxes in 3D with lighting:

[image]

But now I am stuck. My boxes are all in the set ratio 51:63:24. Based on the physical design in mm. From a pixel point of view these ratios are maintained but in the final screen 2D rendition they become distorted, of varying extent depending on the tablet I use, due to the difference between x and y screen resolutions `mDisplayMetrics.xdpi and mDisplayMetrics.ydpi` for each one:

I can see that the final rendition is performed for each face of the box by:

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, offset, 4);
```

My problem is: How do I make this rendition map on to the screen in real perceptive coordinates rather than direct pixel coordinates?

Normally, I use a 2D **`android.graphics.Matrix`** to transform all paths, shapes, images etc to compensate for the screen resolution anisotropy but I can't see how to do it here. Without it, everything becomes extended/compressed in y-direction for portrait or in the x-direction for landscape. For the Android tablet I am currently using, this matrix is **`Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.9469214, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`**. OK, it is only 5.5% off uniformity but if I design boxes in the ratio 51:63:24 I kinda like to see them preserving that ratio without distorting as they rotate. I'm am absolutely sure OpenGL and my supplied face bitmaps are doing their job perfectly. It is only the final 2D projection that I need to allow for. But how?

Can anyone please tell me how I can make this final transformation? Basically, how do I scale, arbitrarily, the final 2D rendering result?

Code for MainActivity:

```
public class MyGLActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static FaceGroup facegroup;
private GLSurfaceView glView;
private DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics;
private Display mDisplay;

// use GLSurfaceView
// Call back when the activity is started, to initialize the view
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWHscalefactor();
    **facegroup = new FaceGroup(this);**
    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);           // Allocate a GLSurfaceView
    glView.setRenderer(new MyGLRenderer()); // Use a custom renderer
    this.setContentView(glView);                // This activity sets to GLSurfaceView
}

// Call back when the activity is going into the background
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    glView.onPause();
}

// Call back after onPause()
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    glView.onResume();
}

private void getWHscalefactor() {
    float unequalDPIscaleW, unequalDPIscaleH;
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mDisplay.getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
    unequalDPIscaleW = 1;
    unequalDPIscaleH = xppi() / yppi();
    if (unequalDPIscaleH > 1) {
        unequalDPIscaleW = 1 / unequalDPIscaleH;
        unequalDPIscaleH = 1;
    }
    m.setScale(unequalDPIscaleW, unequalDPIscaleH);
    System.out.println("Anisotropy Matrix: " + m); }

public float xppi() { return mDisplayMetrics.xdpi; }

public float yppi() { return mDisplayMetrics.ydpi; }
```

The call **`facegroup = new FaceGroup(this);`** simply reads and interprets the path information as supplied in an SVG export from CorelDraw on which the production boxes are designed ready for printing, cutting, folding and gluing. They are the real thing :). **`facegroup`** also creates the required face bitmaps by rendering these paths.

Code for MyGLRenderer:

```
 public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
private GAMZBox gamzBox;     // (NEW)
private static float angleCube = 0;     // rotational angle in degree for gamzBox
private static float speedCube = 0.25f; // rotational speed for gamzBox

// Constructor
public MyGLRenderer() {
    gamzBox = new GAMZBox();    // (NEW)
}

// Call back when the surface is first created or re-created.
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Set color's clear-value to black
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);            // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);    // The type of depth testing to do
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  // nice perspective view
    gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading of color
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);      // Disable dithering for better performance

    // Setup Texture, each time the surface is created (NEW)
    gamzBox.loadTexture(gl);             // Load images into textures (NEW)
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  // Enable texture (NEW)
}

// Call back after onSurfaceCreated() or whenever the window's size changes
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) height = 1;   // To prevent divide by zero
    float aspect = (float)width / height;

    // Set the viewport (display area) to cover the entire window
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Setup perspective projection, with aspect ratio matches viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select projection matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset projection matrix
    // Use perspective projection
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, aspect, 0.1f, 100.f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);  // Select model-view matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset

    // You OpenGL|ES display re-sizing code here
    // ......
}

// Call back to draw the current frame.
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clear color and depth buffers
    float diffuseMaterial[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };

    float mat_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    float light_position[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f };
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // ----- Render the Cube -----
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                  // Reset the model-view matrix
    gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseMaterial, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular, 0);
    gl.glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 25f);
    gl.glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position, 0);
    gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    //gl.glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE);
    gl.glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);   // Translate into the screen
    gl.glRotatef(angleCube, 1f * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(0.1 * angleCube)),
            4.0f * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(0.05 * angleCube)), -0.3f); // Rotate
    gamzBox.draw(gl);

    // Update the rotational angle after each refresh.
    angleCube += speedCube;
}
}
```

and the **`GAMZBox`** object face definitions and drawers are in this code. It is essentially a [photo cube (https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html)](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html) mutatis mutandis to build in my 51:63:24 face ratios. **`bitmaps`** is defined in the **`FaceGroup`** as a **`public static Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[6];`**.

```
public class GAMZBox {
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;  // Vertex Buffer
    private FloatBuffer texBuffer;     // Texture Coords Buffer

    private int numFaces = 6;
    private int[] textureIDs = new int[numFaces];
//    private Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[numFaces];
    private float cubeHalfSize = 24f / 63f; //1.2f;

    // Constructor - Set up the vertex buffer
    public GAMZBox() {
        // Allocate vertex buffer. An float has 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12 * 4 * numFaces);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

        // Read images. Find the aspect ratio and adjust the vertices accordingly.
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            int imgWidth = bitmaps[face].getWidth();
            int imgHeight = bitmaps[face].getHeight();
            System.out.println(imgWidth + ", " + imgHeight);
            float faceWidth = 2.0f;
            float faceHeight = 2.0f;
            if (face > 3) {
                faceWidth *= 51f / 63f;
                faceHeight *= 51f / 63f;
            }
            // Adjust for aspect ratio
            if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
                faceHeight = faceHeight * imgHeight / imgWidth;
            } else {
                faceWidth = faceWidth * imgWidth / imgHeight;
            }
            float faceLeft = -faceWidth / 2;
            float faceRight = -faceLeft;
            float faceTop = faceHeight / 2;
            float faceBottom = -faceTop;

            // Define the vertices for this face
            float[] vertices = {
                    faceLeft,  faceBottom, 0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
                    faceRight, faceBottom, 0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
                    faceLeft,  faceTop,    0.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
                    faceRight, faceTop,    0.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            };
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);  // Populate
        }
        vertexBuffer.position(0);    // Rewind

        // Allocate texture buffer. An float has 4 bytes. Repeat for 6 faces.
        float[] texCoords = {
                0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom
                1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom
                0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top
                1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top
        };
        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4 * numFaces);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            texBuffer.put(texCoords);
        }
        texBuffer.position(0);   // Rewind
    }

    // Render the shape
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer);

        // front
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // left
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 51f/63f); // cubeHalfSize);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[1]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // back
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(180.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, cubeHalfSize);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[2]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // right
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 51f/63f); // cubeHalfSize);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[3]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // top
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 1.0f); //cubeHalfSize);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[4]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // bottom
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 1.0f); //cubeHalfSize);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[5]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    // Load images into 6 GL textures
    public void loadTexture(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glGenTextures(6, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array for 6 IDs

        // Generate OpenGL texture images
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[face]);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture ID
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmaps[face], 0);
            bitmaps[face].recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I solved this issue after reading how to be careful to avoid distortions in a final projection ref: [***The Official Guide to Learning OpenGL, Version 1.1*** **Chapter 3: Viewing**, subtitle: **Viewport Transformation**](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name4).

I changed **`MyGLRenderer`** to the code below. **`getWHscalefactor`** calculates the required scaling factors (**`MScaleW`** and **`mScaleH`**) to compensate for x/y anisotropy in the screen dots per inch values and applied them to:

**`gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int)(width * mScaleW), (int)(height * mScaleH));`**

in the **`OnSurfaceChanged`** callback while leaving the **`aspect`** parameter unchanged in:

**`GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, aspect, 0.1f, 100.f);`**

as the ratio of the original width to the original height. My box now looks correct. :)

I am sorry about this. This can all be deleted if you so ordain. Forgive an old lady. BTW It's not a smartass thing. It is because in forming a question to ask other informed people, like you, it helps me to organise my thoughts and see clearly what the real issues are. Thank you. JosieH :)

```
  public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
private GAMZBox gamzBox;     // (NEW)
private static float angleCube = 0;     // rotational angle in degree for gamzBox
private static float speedCube = 0.25f; // rotational speed for gamzBox
private float mScaleW, mScaleH;

// Constructor
public MyGLRenderer() {
    gamzBox = new GAMZBox();    // (NEW)
}

// Call back when the surface is first created or re-created.
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    getWHscalefactor();
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Set color's clear-value to black
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);            // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);    // The type of depth testing to do
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  // nice perspective view
    gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading of color
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);      // Disable dithering for better performance

    // Setup Texture, each time the surface is created (NEW)
    gamzBox.loadTexture(gl);             // Load images into textures (NEW)
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  // Enable texture (NEW)
}

// Call back after onSurfaceCreated() or whenever the window's size changes
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) height = 1;   // To prevent divide by zero
    float aspect = (float)width / height;

    // Set the viewport (display area) to cover the entire window
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int)(width * mScaleW), (int)(height * mScaleH));

    // Setup perspective projection, with aspect ratio matches viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select projection matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset projection matrix
    // Use perspective projection
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, aspect, 0.1f, 100.f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);  // Select model-view matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset
    // You OpenGL|ES display re-sizing code here
    // ......
}

// Call back to draw the current frame.
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clear color and depth buffers
    float diffuseMaterial[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };

    float mat_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    float light_position[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f };
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // ----- Render the Cube -----
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                  // Reset the model-view matrix
    gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseMaterial, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular, 0);
    gl.glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 25f);
    gl.glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position, 0);
    gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    //gl.glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE);
    gl.glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.2f);   // Translate into the screen
    gl.glRotatef(angleCube, 1f * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(0.1 * angleCube)),
            4.0f * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(0.05 * angleCube)), -0.3f); // Rotate
    gamzBox.draw(gl);

    // Update the rotational angle after each refresh.
    angleCube += speedCube;
}

public void getWHscalefactor() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    Display d = theApp.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    d.getMetrics(dm);

    boolean portrait = dm.heightPixels >= dm.widthPixels;
    if (portrait) {
        mScaleW = 1;
        mScaleH = dm.xdpi / dm.ydpi;
        if (mScaleH > 1) {
            mScaleW = 1 / mScaleH;
            mScaleH = 1;
        }
    } else {
        mScaleW = dm.xdpi / dm.ydpi;
        mScaleH = 1;
        if (mScaleW > 1) {
            mScaleH = 1 / mScaleW;
            mScaleW = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("DPI Scales {" + mScaleW + ", " + mScaleH + "}");
}
}
```